# How to safely extend Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I need more space at for my Ubuntu partition, so I will need to shrink the Data partition and extend the size of the ext4, right? This is the current state of the partitions:

[image]

What is the proper way to achieve this?
Using windows to shrink the Data partition? (An unrelated partition to windows, though).
And then, with an ubuntu live cd, using gparted, extending the size of the ext4 partition to the unallocated space?

**Update-1:**
The state I posted above, was from my laptop. I tried the resizing process at my Desktop and at the step `grow filesystem to fill the partition > real resize` it failed and [here are the details](http://www.sendspace.com/file/7k55vi) (also, on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/H7zFnMiX)).

What can I do?

**Update-2:**
At Gparted, it seems that the process completed successfully. The unallocated space, is the one I've set before the partition shrink process. So, I can assume that everything went good?
Also, if you see, at the bottom of the message, it was asking me to reply `Y/n` but I don't think I could do that via gParted (and not using a terminal).
This is the current state from gParted via Ubuntu Live CD.
[image: State of partitions after the error]

Comment: You should be able to do this all from Live CD/DVD/USB choosing "Try Ubuntu" and then opening **Gparted**. Keep backup of all the partitions in case things go wrong.

Comment: @user68186: I've updated my question with more information, please take a look.

Comment: After reducing the size of data partition,the unallocated space comes under the linux swap partition.Then you can extend the ext4 partition.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: So I can assume that as this step failed, I can extend the ext4 partition to use all the unallocated space?

Comment: you can use only the unallocated space which was inside the extended partition.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: So what can I do now? I've posted the state of the partitions at the question.

Comment: Your actual question was to `use the unallocated space to extend ext4 partition` am i correct?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes I need to extend the capacity of the Ubuntu partition, which is the ext4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From the screenshot,it was clear that you had mounted `extended partition`.It was not possible to `resize` a mounted partition via `gparted`.So you must run a gparted live disk or run a ubuntu live disk and install gparted on it.
- Open `gparted` and right click on the `extended partition`.Now you can add the unallocated space to the extended partition.The unallocated space comes under the linux-swap partition.
- Then rightclick on the `ext4` partition,now you can be able add the unallocated space to the ext4 partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the process completed successfuly. I will do this at my laptop as well. Just in case, if after that I cannot boot, I will have to re-install grub, right?

Comment: yes,if there any problem occurs post here.I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all from the live CD. Probably better to do it from the CD because windows seems to recognise partitions differently to linux.

Comment: I tried doing this at my desktop pc, and I've updated my question with more information, please take a look, there are some errors.